# Induction with triangles

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

We can prove with induction (among other methods) that:

given n non parallel lines such that no three intersect at a point, there are $\binom{n}{3}$ triangles formed.

I need to find exactly how many new triangles will be formed when the (k+1)st line is added (still satisfying that no two of the lines are parallel, and no three of the lines intersect at a single point)

maybe it will be $\binom{k+1}{3}$ or maybe this will be $\frac 12 k(k-1)$?

Comment: Would you mind formatting your question. Look up MathJax/ latex. It's impossible to understand your formulas. What's 2c3?

Comment: k+2 choose 3   ..but yeah ill try to format it

Comment: I would be skeptical of counts like $(1/2)(k - 1)$ since that won't be an integer, half the time (and $(1/3)(k - 1)$ two thirds of the time!)

Comment: sorry what about (1/2) (k) (k-1)??

Comment: @Andrei tried formatting? do you  understand??

Comment: Better. For (n choose 3) use $\binom{n}{3}$ `\binom{n}{3}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** ***Choose*** any two lines in the previous $k$ set, the intersection with the $(k+1)$-th line will create one triangle

Comment: so lets say you have the base case or 3 lines and one triangle like this https://imgur.com/a/sfZq7... then you add a line.... so that line will go through 2 lines and create another triangle.. but other triangles will also be formed no?

Comment: Sure. Your new line will form a triangle with each of the possible choices. How many possibilities are there?

Comment: Go back to the hint. That's why I emphasized "choose". "a choose b" tells you in how many ways you can choose b elements from a set with a elements

Comment: the possible choices are the existing lines. so if you start with 3 lines and then add 1 line you will have 4 triangles... but then how do you generalize this to the k+1 and k+2

Comment: When you add the $(k+1)$-th line you add $\binom{k}{2}$ new triangles compared to the case with $k$ lines. When you add the $(k+2)$-th line you add $\binom{k+1}{2}$ new triangles compared to the case with $k+1$ lines.

Comment: hmmmm I see because lets say you have k=2 then 2 lines and 0 triangles but when you add the (k+1)th line (2 choose 2) is 1 and you now have one triangle.... but why does this work?? and for the last part you would just sum (k choose 3)+ (k choose 2) +(k+1 choose 2) right?

Comment: It works because your lines must intersect. And for all possible choices of two lines out of $k$, you add one more triangle.